# How to capture the incoming data from MSTeam?

Tags: post, botframework, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I have configured a outgoing webhook in msteam which should capture the data user is passing in the api and display over console or msteam.How can it be done?
Currently i have tried this and could capure the incoming data but the same is not working in the base Controller

```
public async Task<Activity> gettestdata()
    {
        string content = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Activity incomingActivity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity>(content);
        return incomingActivity;
    }
```

Any other method is there to do the same as in Base Controller( public class TestController : Controller) the below command is not supported,it says 'Content' cannot be found

```
string content = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: I notice that you're using the `botframework` tag. Are you building a bot?

Comment: yes using bot framework

Comment: @Priya.D- If I understand correctly, you are building [Outgoing Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook) and not a [Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots). Could you please try [Outgoing Webhook samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook#code-samples)?

Comment: @Priya.D - Are you still working on this? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: I am trying to build outgoing webhook and trying to integrate in existing appications, samples works fine but when i try to build my own it doesnot seem to work.Can you guide me with easy sample solution?@Wajeed-MSFT

Comment: @KyleDelaney: yes working on this, trying to create a outgoing webhook in my existing applications,where message from msteam should be received by my api using outgoing webhook .

Comment: @Priya.D - It's unclear how you're communicating with this webhook and what data you're trying to pass to it and what problems you're having. If the samples work then it's up to you to do the work of figuring out what makes your webhook different from the samples. If you've tried to do that and you've encountered an obstacle that you can't overcome then you need to ask a specific question about that specific problem rather than asking strangers on the Internet to "guide" you for free. Please post repro steps and screenshots to help explain your problem.

Comment: @KyleDelaney: As i am new to this,I have tried to explain in my way how much i could (also shared code and not asking free guidance),if it is getting difficult for you to guide and help strangers then please simply ignore.

Comment: @Priya.D - Sorry for my rudeness. Have you tried starting with a sample and then adding features one at a time to make it more like your webhook to see which part makes it fail?